# How to fix php error "Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference"?

Tags: php, drupal

I know that on stackoverflow there was a lot of similar problems with this error, but none solve my problem. I have a function in `high_contrast.module` file:

```php
function high_contrast_install() {
  $background = \Drupal::config('high_contrast.settings')->get('colors_background');
  $text = \Drupal::config('high_contrast.settings')->get('colors_text');
  $hyperlinks = \Drupal::config('high_contrast.settings')->get('colors_hyperlinks');

  \Drupal::service('file_system')->prepareDirectory(HIGH_CONTRAST_CSS_FOLDER, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY); // LINE 17!!!
  $css = _high_contrast_build_css();
  file_save_data($css, HIGH_CONTRAST_CSS_LOCATION, FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
```

and when I want to install the module, I have en error:

```
Error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in high_contrast_install() (line 17 of modules\high_contrast\high_contrast.install).
```

How can I fix it? :(

Line 17 is that one:

```
  \Drupal::service('file_system')->prepareDirectory(HIGH_CONTRAST_CSS_FOLDER, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY);
```

Comment: Presumably one of `'file_system'` or `HIGH_CONTRAST_CSS_FOLDER` is supposed to be a variable, not a constant.

Comment: So...@Nick, it should be something like `\Drupal::service('file_system')->prepareDirectory($a = HIGH_CONTRAST_CSS_FOLDER, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY);`? It not helps.

Comment: [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystemInterface.php/function/FileSystemInterface%3A%3AprepareDirectory/8.7.x) might help - the first argument passed to `prepareDirectory()` must be a reference, use `&directory` - e.g. `public function prepareDirectory(&$directory, $options = self::MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error suggests, [`FileSystem::prepareDirectory`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3AprepareDirectory/8.7.x) takes its first argument by reference :

```
public function prepareDirectory(&$directory, $options = self::MODIFY_PERMISSIONS) {
  # $directory being assigned new value
}
```

So PHP throws an error if you pass it a [constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) :

> A constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. As the name
>   suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script

You need to assign the constant value to a variable before the function call :

```
$dir = HIGH_CONTRAST_CSS_FOLDER;
\Drupal::service('file_system')->prepareDirectory($dir, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY);
```